# SCNProgram – How to pass a uniform of type "mat4" to a custom shader?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to set a uniform mat4 that I want to use in a custom shader program in SceneKit on iOS (Xcode 6 beta 6). And I'm trying to do that in Swift.

```
let myMatrix: Array<GLfloat> = [1, 0, 0 , 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

var material = SCNMaterial()
var program = SCNProgram()

// setup of vertex/fragment shader goes here
program.vertexShader = //...
program.fragmentShader = //...

material.program = program

// I want to initialize the variable declared as "uniform mat4 u_matrix" in the vertex shader with "myMatrix"

material.handleBindingOfSymbol("u_matrix") {
    programID, location, renderedNode, renderer in            
    let numberOfMatrices = 1
    let needToBeTransposed = false
    glUniformMatrix4fv(GLint(location), GLsizei(numberOfMatrices), GLboolean(needToBeTransposed), myMatrix)
}
```

Using this code, I have the following compilation error: `Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type (GLint, GLsizei, GLboolean, Array<GLfloat>)`. However, from this documentation here ([section "Constant pointers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)) it is my understanding that we can pass an array to a function that takes an UnsafePointer as argument.

I then tried to directly pass an UnsafePointer by doing the following:

```
let testPtr: UnsafePointer<GLfloat> = nil
glUniformMatrix4fv(GLint(location), GLsizei(numberOfMatrices), GLboolean(needToBeTransposed), testPtr)
```

And I got the error `Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(GLint, GLsizei, GLboolean, UnsafePointer<GLfloat>)'`

However, the prototype of glUniformMatrix4fv is exactly that:

```
func glUniformMatrix4fv(location: GLint, count: GLsizei, transpose: GLboolean, value: UnsafePointer<GLfloat>)
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? How are we supposed to pass a mat4 as an uniform if we use a custom shader?

**Note1**: I first attempted to use a SCNMatrix4 for myMatrix but I got the error "SCNMatrix4 is not convertible to UnsafePointer".

**Note2**: I thought of using GLKMatrix4 but this type is not recognized in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the compiler's error messages can provide more misdirection than help when figuring out how to call C APIs. My troubleshooting technique has been to declare each parameter as a local variable and see which one gets the red flag. In this case, it's not the last parameter that's causing problems, it's the `GLboolean`.

```
let aTranspose = GLboolean(needToBeTransposed)
// Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'Bool'
```

Turns out GLboolean is defined this way:

```
typealias GLboolean = UInt8
```

So this is the code we need:

```
material.handleBindingOfSymbol("u_matrix") {
    programID, location, renderedNode, renderer in

    let numberOfMatrices = 1
    let needToBeTransposed = false

    let aLoc = GLint(location)
    let aCount = GLsizei(numberOfMatrices)
    let aTranspose = GLboolean(needToBeTransposed ? 1 : 0)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(aLoc, aCount, aTranspose, myMatrix)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nate. It works. I'm just not sure to understand. Why `GLboolean(false)` does not work but `GLboolean(false ? 1 : 0)` does? They both produce a GLboolean.

Comment: Boolean values are typically represented in C as 0 (zero) for false and nonzero (usually 1) for true. Those integer values then work wherever a Boolean expression is needed, like in an `if` statement. (Swift imports `GLboolean` as just an alias to an `Int8` for this reason). Compare that to the Swift-native `Bool` type, which is a `struct` with some internal value. This difference is why you can't simply initialize a `GLboolean` with a Swift-native Bool value, but can with a 1 or a 0.